# inserting a dynamically generated $_POST values from a form into mysql from php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying currently to insert back into a database values from my form.

```
 <?php do { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row_questions['question']; ?><br /><table><tr><td style=

    "padding:15px; text-align:center">
      <label>
        <center><input type="radio" name="answers_<?php echo $row_questions['id']; ?>_<?php echo $row_questions['sub_category']; ?>" value="1" id="answers_1" /></center><br />
        Low</label>
      </td><td style="padding:15px; text-align:center">
      <label>
        <center><input type="radio" name="answers_<?php echo $row_questions['id']; ?>_<?php echo $row_questions['sub_category']; ?>" value="2" id="answers_2" /></center><br />
        Fairly Low</label>
      </td><td style="padding:15px; text-align:center">
      <label>
        <center><input type="radio" name="answers_<?php echo $row_questions['id']; ?>_<?php echo $row_questions['sub_category']; ?>" value="3" id="answers_3" /></center><br />
        Average</label>
      </td><td style="padding:15px; text-align:center">
      <label>
        <center><input type="radio" name="answers_<?php echo $row_questions['id']; ?>_<?php echo $row_questions['sub_category']; ?>" value="4" id="answers_4" /></center><br />
        Fairly High </label>
      </td><td style="padding:15px; text-align:center">
      <label>
        <center><input type="radio" name="answers_<?php echo $row_questions['id']; ?>_<?php echo $row_questions['sub_category']; ?>" value="5" id="answers_5" /></center><br />
        High</label>
      </td></tr></table><br />
  </tr>
  <?php } while ($row_questions = mysql_fetch_assoc($questions)); ?>
```

the form gets the questions from a table in my database (called questions). they are in three categories and only one categories set of questions is pulled at any one time.

I need to insert each answer individually into another table (called user_answers).

I'm having trouble working out quite how to go about this and it's beginning to do my head in!

the form manages to pass through $_POST a value that when I `print_r($_POST);` I get

> Array ( [answers_90_5] => 3 [answers_91_5] => 3 )

With 90 & 91 being the question ids and 5 being the subcategory in both instances.

From here I am stumped.

How do I identify these parts of each individual post along with the answer and insert them as a row each in the table?

I'm fine with doing the MySQL insert normally and a standard form passing values etc. but I'm completely stumped on how to do this!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: consider that your loop is backwards. You don't fetch a row of data until AFTER you've output a chunk of html, so you'll always be outputting one empty block. this should be a `while($row = ...) { ... } ` loop instead.

Comment: Not sure I understand where you are stuck.  Can't you simply loop over the $_POST data and craft the inserts?  All the needed data is there. Am I missing something?

Comment: crafting the inserts is where my brain is failing me. I think the answer is right in front of my I just can't think how to construct it.

Answer (score 3):

Using a multi-dimensional array should ease your job of iteration:

```
<input 
    type="radio" 
    name="answers[<?php echo $row_questions['id']; ?>][<?php echo $row_questions['sub_category']; ?>]" 
    value="1" 
    id="answers_<?php echo $row_questions['id'] . '_' . $row_questions['sub_category']; ?>" />
```

Debugging this should give you `$_POST` filled with a array of the likes:

```
Array ( [answers] => Array(
     90 => Array ( 5 => 3 ),
     91 => Array ( 5 => 3 ),
))
```

Comment: This will help you immensely, rather than having to parse out these arrays from you input name they way you would need to in your original form code.

Comment: Edited answer to also give your input a dynamic id property, as these should be unique for the entire document.

Comment: Correct. To explain the general idea: `<input name="foo[bar]">` results in $_POST being a multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

sure, separate your queries, post val one and sub cat one for query 1, and query 2 do the same for cat 2 and sub cat two.

very simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answer suggesting multi-dim arrays makes a lot of sense.  Thought I would still provide an example on how to parse the string though.  It could be something as simple as:

```
foreach ($post as $k => $v) {
    $parts = explode('_', $k);
    $questionId = $parts[1];            
    $questionCategoryId = $parts[2];    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO answers (questionId, subCategoryId, answerValue ) VALUES ($questionId, $questionCategoryId, $v)";

    ....
}
```

... only hopefully with better escaping on the POST data.